# Skip the route parameter from being passed to the closure function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Is it possible to skip the route parameter from being passed to the closure function in **Laravel 10.x**? For example, do not pass the `locale` to the closure function.

```
Route::get('/{locale}/{parem1}/{parem2}', function (Request $request, $param1, $param2) {

    echo "$param1 : $param2";
    
})->whereIn('locale', ['an', 'ar']);
```

Comment: [Route parameters are injected into route callbacks / controllers based on their order - the names of the route callback / controller arguments do not matter.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#:~:text=Route%20parameters%20are%20injected%20into%20route%20callbacks%20/%20controllers%20based%20on%20their%20order%20%2D%20the%20names%20of%20the%20route%20callback%20/%20controller%20arguments%20do%20not%20matter.)